# Problems installing flutter APK on real device

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

So, I'm trying to install my APK on my real phone with is a LG G7. When I drag and drop the apk to documents and try to install, it just says that the APK can't be installed, doesn't give me any errors. I got another phone, with was Samsung note 9, and when attempting to install the APK, it worked fine, does someone know why my phone can't install my apk? I have allowed USB depuration in settings already.

Comment: Are you using the APK from the debug folder or release folder?

Comment: The one that I'm using is from release, that one worked on the Samsung device

Comment: I assume you have enabled app installation from external sources too in LG

Comment: I have done that too

Answer (score 0):

Generate apk by the following command

`flutter build apk --split-per-abi`

Usually `build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk` works on most of the phones. Try installing the other two as well.